# Как передать функцию в скобки?

Tags: php

Если смотреть в [документацию](https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/wiki/Attributes), то можно увидеть такую строчку:

```
attr($key, $fn) Set a single property to a computed value, on all matched elements.
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно передать функцию в скобки?
Насколько я знаю, в скобки функцию нельзя писать, тогда что тут имелось в виду?

Answer (score 1):

[Анонимные функции](https://php.net/manual/ru/functions.anonymous.php) в помощь.

Answer (score 1):

**Насколько**. PHP может вызвать:

- Строку, содержащую fully qualified function name: `\Name\Space\fnc`. По понятным причинам чаще всего употребляются функции без неймспейсов, например `array_map('intval', $idList);`.
- Строку, содержащую fully qualified static method name `\Name\Space\Clazz::method`. Это вызовет соответствующий статический метод.
- Анонимную функцию (в реальности - экземпляр класса Closure)
- Объект, у которого есть метод `__invoke()` (к предыдущему пункту)
- Массив, состоящий из объекта и имени метода: `array($this, 'init')`

Все это спокойно съест и выполнит `call_user_func` / `call_user_func_array()`, одна из которых скорее всего и лежит внутри метода phpquery.